# Run the following command to install 'ipykernel' into the Python environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, python-venv

```
 import pandas as pandas
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import cv2
from PIL import Image
```

When I run the above line of code I get the following error:

*Running cells with 'c:\Users\NESLİHAN\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.11.exe' requires the ipykernel package.
Run the following command to install 'ipykernel' into the Python environment.
Command: '"c:/Users/NESLİHAN/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe" -m pip install ipykernel -U --user --force-reinstall'*

It has been explained before on this site and I have tried one by one what has been written, but the result is still the same. I also get the error 'Running cells with 'c:\Users\NESLİHAN\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.11.exe' requires the ipykernel package.' I installed the Jupyter plugin. I also wrote what I need to write in Settings>.json, but I can't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More information about the ide you are running would be fine, but I guess you are working on vscode, because you are talking about jupyter plugin. This is a common problem when dealing with jupyter kernels. **You are probably working with a python kernel that has no ipykernel installed**. This is an essential library for jupyter to initialize the mini kernel and work with python in jupyter.

First, you need to be sure you have the [ipykernell library installed](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html). You can do 2 different things to check it. One is

```
python3 -m pip install ipykernel
```

or the second one, which is checking it out manually if you have it installed in your python environment

```
python3 -m pip list
```

If you are sure you have this **ipykernell installed, then you need to check if jupyter notebooks have the same python while creating the kernel**. To check this, you can click on the top right of the screen and check if the python used is the same as the python where you installed everything. The installation path would help you with this.

Since you are in windows, you can open up a CMD and type 'where python3' and check the folder where your python3 is installed.

Another common error while dealing with **jupyter kernels is to work with the global environment vs virtual environment**. You need to be sure to **ALWAYS** work with your **virtual environment**. In case you don't, you are installing libraries globally, which is a bad practice.

[Set up your venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), activate it and then inside your venv install the ipykernel by just typing

```
pip install ipykernel
```

If it's the first time you are using the virutal environment, you need to check if all your libraries are installed, this is done by listing them with the pip list command while your venv is active. In the top right corner, where you choose the python version for your kernel, there will appear the 'venv python3.11: C:/where/your/env/is'. This is the one you need to choose.

To fully understand what's going on, you need to have a basic knowledge of python package manager, python global/virtual environments and jupyter kernel initialization and selection. In both of the links you'll be able to read everything about.

Comment: pip install ipykernel
when I run this command I get the following error:
ERROR: Failed to install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\NESLİHAN\\\AppData\\\Local\\\Packages\\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3 .11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python311\\site-packages\\\jedi\\third_party\\django-stubs\\\django-stubs\\contrib\\contenttypes\\management\\\\commands\\\remove_stale_contenttypes.pyi'

Comment: You have a problem with your python installation. You need to remove the MAX_PATH limitation. This limitation causes a crash when you try to install packages if your installation path is too long, like it seems it is. You have 2 options, try to reinstall path and click on the 'delete max_path limitation' in the install wizzard, or remove it in your current python installation. The second one usually is faster. Check the link in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/windows.html#removing-the-max-path-limitation

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Please, upvote and accept my response if you can :)